# Same complex exponent expression with two different values

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation

I have some issue with $\exp(j)$ and I'm not sure what is the origin of it.

On one side: $\exp(j*\pi) = -1$

On the other side I can write:
$$\exp\left(j*(2\pi)*\tfrac 1 2\right) = \exp(j*(2\pi))^{0.5} = 1^{0.5} = 1$$

Well $1$ is not equal to $-1$.
What did i do wrong?

Thank you

Comment: $(z^n)^m = z^{nm}$ only holds when $m$ is an integer for complex $z$.

Comment: Hey, what do you mean by "m  is an integer for complex z"? thank you! @Fenris

Comment: For complex numbers $z$ the relation $(z^n)^m = z^{nm}$ holds generally when $m$ is an integer. However, it does not hold when $m$ is rational as in your case.

Comment: WOW. Did not know that. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! Your example serves as a counterexample. For full understanding, it would be instructive for you to try to prove by induction that the relation holds for integer $m$.

Comment: Note that $(z^n)^m = z^{nm}$ doesn't even always hold when $z$ is real, unless $m,n$ are integers. A highly relevant example is $((-1)^2)^{1/2} \ne (-1)^{2(1/2)}$. $(z^n)^m = z^{nm}$ can only be depended on when $z$ is a *positive* real number, or $m,n$ are both integer.